# ASP.NET Chart Control Issue

Tags: asp.net

I'm using ASP.net chart control of type `column`.

And I have my data table to bind it to the chart:

- column 1 of type string for `XValueMember`
- column 2 of type integer for `YValueMembers`

Let's say that I have 15 records in the datatable. When I bind the datatable to chart, **only 4 or 3 values appears in XValueMember**. I need all records to be displayed on `XValueMember`.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself , I Added :

```
<AxisX Interval="1"> </AxisX>
```